# Value passed from one function to another changes... Can't figure out why?

Tags: c, windows, dll

I have a very weird problem that I can't understand.

This is C code:

```
//below are the values being passed
//long numTreePeriods = 80
//double length = 0.23013698630136986
TTimeLineInfo* tlInfo = GtoTimeLineInfoNew( (long)ceil(numTreePeriods/length), /*ppy*/
                               0L,
                               1,
                               FALSE);
```

Now here's the signature of the GtoTimeLineInfoNew function called above:

```
__declspec(dllexport) TTimeLineInfo*   GtoTimeLineInfoNew
    (long             minPPY,       /* (I) Min # ppy before switchDate */
     TDate            switchDate,   /* (I) If 0, ignore ppy2; only use minPPY*/
     long             minPPY2,      /* (I) Min # ppy after switchDate */
     TBoolean         wholeDayTPs);
```

When I debug my code and step into the function with the values specified above I get:

```
minPPY = -1636178017
```

????? What could cause this type of behaviour?

Just to precise the C code is a dll I am wrapping up in C++/CLI. Nevertheless the problem seems independent from that....

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint to observe this value? Inside the body of the function?

Comment: What do you actually do with minPPY in the function?

Comment: I put the breakpoint at the function call in the first piece of code, then step into it and step over a few lines to make sure that the values show.

the function initialises a TTimeLineInfo data structure which contains a field where minPPY is copied to... and then returns this ds.... The problem is that a wrong value is copied into the field...

Comment: what does `printf("%f %d", numTreePeriods/length, numTreePeriods/length)` output?

Comment: What is the definition of TDate? It could be that the definition is different between the calling code and the DLL resulting in minPPY being read from the wrong place in the stack or being pushed on in the wrong place.

Comment: I gave the values of numTreePeriods and length in the first piece of code (in the comments). I then expect **80/0.23013698630136986 = 348**. Regarding printf, it's an external dll I can't modify the code without recompiling everything. In theory it has been tested and works.

Comment: TDate is a long in the C code. The calling code is C++/CLI to which the C library has been linked and therefore uses the C definition directly. But I'm thinking along the lines of a problem in the stack as well but don't know well how I can verify this. Note that I have already wrapped a dozen functions with TDate's, and other ds without having this problem...

Comment: Are you sure you have the calling convention correctly specified? Are the other parameters passed properly?

Comment: @nche: put `(long)ceil(numTreePeriods/length)` in a variable before the function call, and check what its value is with the debugger. If you get the expected value, it's almost positively a mismatch of calling conventions (the declspec). Make sure this is the same in all relevant declarations and implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `ceil(numTreePeriods/length)` was giving something very weird. So I wrote a ceil function myself to solve this problem...

UPDATE:

Like highlighted in comment by glglgl, the appropriate header was missing, hence ceil was interpreted to return an int which led to funny values...

Comment: was the appropriate header missing? `ceil()` returns `double`. If the header is missing, it is interpreted to return `int` and strangs things happen...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain; but my guess would be a difference between how parameters are passed to a C function vs. a C++ function.  Try:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TTimeLineInfo* GtoTimeLineInfoNew ...
```